# Have yaml redirect "/hello/" to "/hello"

Tags: django, google-app-engine

Atm, when trying to access

www.eyalw.com/1keyboard/
you get nothing,

but when accessing
www.eyalw.com/1keyboard

you get the correct page.

this is the current yaml:

```
application: eyalwcom
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: no

handlers:

- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html

- url: /1keyboard
  static_files: static/1keyboard.html
  upload: static/1keyboard.html

- url: /
  static_dir: static

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

Comment: Try adding `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = ""` to your [django settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#force-script-name)

Answer (score 1):

You can put in a regexp to match your url.
I'm not certain I can get the right regexp off the top of my head, I think it would be:

```
- url: /1keyboard/?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a trailing slash to always be added you can use a RedirectRoute from webapp2 with `strict_slash=True`, as described here: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/routes.html#webapp2_extras.routes.RedirectRoute[1](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/routes.html#webapp2_extras.routes.RedirectRoute)

Instead of adding this to your app.yaml file you would include this where you defined the other routes and linked them to handlers.